# What are the differences between using .first() and .eq(0)?

Tags: jquery

What are the difference between using these 2 methods for retrieving the first element in a collection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taken from the [live source code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js) of jQuery 1.7.1:

```
,first:function(){return this.eq(0)},last:function(){return this.eq(-1)}
```

So as you suspected `.first()` is just a wrapper calling `.eq()`.

Conclusion: no difference whatsoever. :)

Comment: +1! So its just A syntactic sugar..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no difference.

Comment: That's quite unlikely, there's no reason for implementing two functions that do the same thing. I suspect the `first` method to be a wrapper for `eq(0)`, but am not sure.

Comment: They don't do the same. `eq()` can also fetch the e.g. 5th element, `first()` cannot. I suppose that `first()` is just a convenient wrapper for a specific case.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: He's asking about `eq(0)` specifically with `0` as an argument, so they're the same.

Comment: [0] applied to a collection returns the DOM object itself, not a jQuery object.

Comment: There is a reason _even if_ both are same in performance. `eq(n)` can be (and is) used inside loops to iterate over the elements in collections (arrays) in non-sequential manner.

Comment: Right. I believe it is also for consistency with the selectors in CSS.