# Difference between using eq(0) and not using it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

When I want to run a jQuery function on a single element that has the class .pizza, I do this:

```
$('.pizza').hide();
```

What is the difference between that and using [first() or eq(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896577/what-are-the-differences-between-using-first-and-eq0)?

```
$('.pizza').eq(0).hide();
```

My question comes because I want to cache the element into a variable to use it many times, and I don't know if it is a better practice to do:

```
var element_pizza=$('.pizza').eq(0);
```

Or just simply:

```
var element_pizza=$('.pizza');
```

**Note**: When I mean on a single element, I mean that there is only one element with the class pizza in the DOM.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: when you have a single element with a class, then there is no need to use `eq(0)` at that place. That is simply unnecessary. And that will costs you additional function calls.

Comment: If there is only one element with class .pizza then i would suggest to use $('.pizza').hide(); because $('.pizza').eq(0).hide(); is used to match the 0th element from a set. But in your case you don't have a set of elements instead you have only one element.

Comment: @koolhuman Doesn't he have a set of elements, just a set-size of `1`?  It's still returned as a jQuery-array.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher thanks for pointing that out. basically i meant when the set is > 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference when the set contains only one match.

Using `.eq()` would only be to select one specific match from a set. If the set has one element, then they will be equivalent.

In fact, it is a waste to use `.eq(0)` if the set contains one element because that will cause a new jQuery object to be created.